# Close SQLCL window off after executing 2 scripts in parallel from a .bat file

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

I have the following .bat file that calls 2 sql scripts.

```
start C:\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin\sql javi/pwd@tnsname @"mypath1"
start C:\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin\sql javi/pwd@tnsname @"mypath2"
```

However, when I execute this, the SQLCL windows that are opened in parallel are not closed when the execution ends. What can I add to close them off if no error is raised during the executions?

Comment: SQL scripts should then end with an "exit" statement.

Comment: @p3consulting would there be any way to achieve the same result in the command line itself just to allow the script to be compatible with, let´s say SQL Developer?

Comment: How to you imagine the .bat could reconnect to the same existing session?
the only alternative would be to "pipe" the file then the "exit" command to the same sqlcl process instead of using the @ command.